# JQuery Click using enter key not clicking

Tags: jquery, click

I have the following code which works as it should... a user enters text in a text box then clicks enter to save it:

```
$('#tagit #btnsave').live('click',function(){
    name = $('#tagName').val();
    counter++;
    $('#taglist ol').append('<li rel="'+counter+'"><a>'+name+'</a> (<a class="remove">Remove</a>)</li>');
    $('#imgtag').append('<div class="tagview" id="view_'+counter+'"></div>');
    $('#view_' + counter).css({top:mouseY,left:mouseX});
    $('#tagit').fadeOut();
});
```

What I want to do is to be able to use the enter button instead of having to click the `#btnsave` button, so I'm trying:

```
$('#tagName').keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $('#tagit #btnsave').click();
    }
});
```

But it does nothing - is there a better way to do this?

Comment: live is deprecated as of jquery 1.7

Comment: `$('#tagit #btnsave').click();` is not required `$('#btnsave').click();` is sufficient since you are using id selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with **.trigger** like

```
$('#tagName').keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $('#btnsave').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

And try to avoid .live function due to it is depricated.Instead of .live try with .on like

```
$('#tagit #btnsave').on('click',function(){
```

Comment: try my edit ,I have removed the tagit,you need to mention only btnsave

Comment: The proper format for live events now would be `$(document).on('click', '#btnsave', function() {});`

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst Np,both are same

Comment: I know,one is for on and one is for trigger

Comment: Working now thank you but its clicking twice! Nightmare, will start a new question

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) in jQuery

```
 $('#tagit #btnsave').trigger("click");
```

and use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `.live()`.Because it is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful what `#tagName` refers to as you're binding the keyup event to that element. The event will only run if that element is selected. You can bind the event to the window if you want the event to always occur when enter is pressed.